# Confused on what variable this refers to in Calculus I (Related Rates)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A spotlight on the ground shines on a wall $12 \mbox{ m}$ away. If a man $2 \mbox{ m}$ tall walks from the spotlight toward the building at a speed of $2.2\mbox{ m/s}$, how fast is the length of his shadow on the building decreasing when he is $4 \mbox{ m}$ from the building?

I labeled the height of the wall a $y$ 
the man is $2\mbox{ m}$ tall.
the distance between the spotlight and building is $12 \mbox{ m}$.
the distance between the light and person is $x$
the distance between the building and the person is $12-x$.

I'm confused about the $2.2\mbox{ m/s}$ I think it's the male's speed which may be negative, but I am not sure how a "Man" can shrink in size. but anyways.

I crossed multiplied to get $y = 24x^{-1}$.
then take the derivative of y to get $dy/dx = -24x^{-2} * dx/dt$.

I can substitute $8$ in for the length of $12-x$ because $x = 4$ in the problem (4 meters)

I get $dy/dx = -24/64 * dx/dt$.

I am lost here and I know I am almost finished with the answer.

Comment: It turns out that things are nearly correct, except that $\frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac{24}{64}\frac{dx}{dt}$ when the person is $4$ m from the wall.Now use $\frac{dx}{dt}=2.2$ to finish. By the way, when the person is $4$ m from the wall then $x=8$.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct with $x*y=24$. Now you just have to use the product rule to differentiate $x*y$.

$x*y = 24 \Rightarrow \frac{dx}{dt}*y+\frac{dy}{dt}*x=24$

Now you can plug in $\frac{dx}{dt}=2.2$, $x=4$, $y=24x^{-1}=\frac{24}{4}=6$ and solve for $\frac{dy}{dt}$.